# SQL não retorna todos os resultados que deveria retornar

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas em meu banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e desejo de selecionar todos os produtos de determinado site (site este marcado pelo usuário através de um *checkbox*) com a seguinte `sql`:

```
SELECT Eletrodomestico 
FROM Produtos 
WHERE URL LIKE (SELECT URL FROM site WHERE id = 1) || '%';
```

porem só me é retornado o primeiro registro do banco, no caso `liquidificador`.

Comment: A tabela `Produtos` não tem `id`?

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, são autoincrementados julguei que não seriam relevantes ao problema, são? pois posso pô-los aqui.

Comment: São porque estás a fazer `WHERE id = 1` e o que acontece é que assume o `id` da tabela `Produtos`

Comment: @RicardoHenrique só uma pequena nota, esse query não é nada escalável. Caso seja possível, eu aconselhava a redesenhar a estrutura da base de dados, ou quando essas tabelas tiverem muitas linhas, o query vai ser muito lento.

Comment: Poderia dar-me uma sugestão? sim e for muito extensa o meu email esta disponivel no meu perfil

Comment: @RicardoHenrique a melhoria é facil. a tabela de produtos deve ter 1 ID que deve ser uma foreign key para o site a que corresponde. nunca fazer joins e comparações com campos de texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Electrodomestico
FROM Produtos p
INNER JOIN Sites s
   ON locate(s.URL, s.URL) > 0
WHERE s.id = 1
```

Isto deve devolver todos os registos.

Edit: Da forma que tu pretendes fazer podes tentar:

```
SELECT Eletrodomestico 
FROM Produtos 
WHERE URL LIKE CONCAT((SELECT URL FROM sites WHERE id = 1), '%');
```

A tua instrução original não funcionou porque || não concatena duas strings. Essa sintax é válida no DB2 mas não no MySql. No MySql o operador [||](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) é o "Ou".
Traduzindo a tua instrução para português resulta em:

Devolve todos os registos para os quais

- URL na tabela Produtos é igual ao URL na tabela Sites
- ou '%' é verdadeiro. Mas esta segunda condição avalia para FALSO.

Para perceberes melhor, e como brincadeira podes substituir a tua query original por:

```
SELECT Eletrodomestico FROM Produtos WHERE URL LIKE (SELECT URL FROM site WHERE id = 1) || 1;
```

Deixo apenas uma opinião. Seria bastante mais fácil se pudesses guardar na tabela Produtos o ID do Site. Facilitava e muito, a junção das tabelas. Sendo que influencia também na performance.

Comment: Funcionou mas poderia me explicar a sua SQL e o que estava de errado na minha SQL?

Comment: Vou editar para tentar explicar o porquê.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Eletrodomestico 
FROM Produtos, Sites
WHERE Sites.URL LIKE 
CONCAT(Produtos.URL, '%') AND  
Sites.id = 1;
```

Basicamente busca pela url do site dentro da url do produto, faz uma junção entre os registros e imprime o que passar pelo filtro incluindo id do site.